# About Sylvester's determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-analysis

- If $A$ is any $n \times m$ matrix and $B$ is any $m \times n$ matrix then one familiar form of the Sylvester's identity is $\det(I + AB) = \det(I + BA)$.

  Now somehow curiously this above identity is often enough used along side another statement which says that for any vector $v$ and any invertible square matrix $A$, it is true that $\det(A + v v^T) = \det(A)\det(I + v^TA^{-1}v)$.

  Is there some relationship between these two identities? Like can one be gotten from the other or vice versa?
- A particularly useful (at least in some recent big breakthrough researches!) form of the Sylvester's identity is when $A= tu, B = v^\dagger $ where ($u$ and $v$ are complex vectors and $t$ is some complex number). This then shows that $\det(I + t u v^\dagger) = 1 + tv^\dagger u$

Now this simple statement above apparently implies this more powerful formulation which is not clear to me - If $C$ is any $n\times n$ (necessarily invertible?) matrix and $A$ is a rank-$1$ matrix then is $\det( I + tCA)$  is a degree $1$ polynomial in $t$? Why? (and this is the same as saying that this is "affine-linear" in t?)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For the first point, note that by Sylvester's identity

$$\det(I_1 + v^TA^{-1}v) = \det(I_1 + (v^T)(A^{-1}v)) = \det(I_n+(A^{-1}v)(v^T)) = \det(I_n + A^{-1}vv^T),$$

so

$$\det(A)\det(I_1+v^TA^{-1}v) = \det(A)\det(I_n + A^{-1}vv^T) = \det(A + vv^T).$$

Given $u \in \mathbb{R}^m$ and $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$, their *outer product* is the $m\times n$ matrix $uv^T$. If $u$ and $v$ are non-zero, then their outer product has rank one. Conversely, a rank one $m\times n$ matrix can be written as the outer product of some non-zero $u$ and $v$.

Now suppose $C$ is an $n\times n$ matrix (not necessarily invertible) and $A$ is a rank one $n\times n$ matrix. By the above discussion, there are $u, v \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $A = uv^T$. So

\begin{align*}
\det(I_n + tCA) &= \det(I_n + tCuv^T)\\ 
&= \det(I_n + (tCu)(v^T))\\ 
&= \det(I_1 + (v^T)(tCu))\\ 
&= \det(I_1 + tv^TCu)\\ 
&= 1 + tv^TCu
\end{align*}

where the last equality follows because $I_1 + tv^TCu$ is a $1\times 1$ matrix.

A function of the form $f(t) = at + b$ is called *affine*. I'm guessing this is what is meant by affine-linear.

**Added Later:** Let me add a theorem which further demonstrates the relationship between the rank of a matrix and outer products. In the following statement, I am taking the definition of the rank of a matrix to be the dimension of its column space.

> **Theorem:** An $m\times n$ matrix $A$ has rank $k$ if and only if  the minimal number of outer products needed to express $A$ as a sum is $k$ (i.e. $A$ can be written as the sum of $k$ outer products, but not $k - 1$).

Proving this is a really nice exercise in elementary linear algebra. I would hate to rob you of the experience by posting the solution here.

Comment: So the crucial thing here seems to be the fact that "A rank one m×n matrix can be written as the outer product of some non-zero u and v." Can you kindly reference this?

Comment: @Anirbit: that is more or less the definition of being rank one.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan :'( That is somehow not very familiar to me. Can you sketch the argument may be?

Comment: @Anirbit Let $S$ be an $m \times n$ matrix of rank $1$. By the rank-nullity theorem, the nullity of $S$ is $(n-1)$, and hence the orthogonal complement of the nullspace of $S$ is $1$-dimensional; pick a unit vector $v$ in the orthogonal complement of the nullspace of $S$. You can then check that $S = uv^T$ for $u := Sv$.

Comment: $\text{det}(I_n + v^T A^{-1}v)$ perhaps should just be $1 + v^T A^{-1}v$. At least it should be $I_1$ not $I_n$.

Comment: @passerby51: You're right. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

The common ground of those two formulas is related to the [Woodbury matrix identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodbury_matrix_identity). This relation is a useful statement that shows what happens to the inverse when one "updates" a matrix $A\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ with a term $UCV$, with $U,V\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times m}$, $C\in\mathbb{C}^{m\times m}$. The typical situation is when $m<n$ and this update is a small-rank term. The rank-1 version, often useful in its own, is called [Sherman–Morrison formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman%E2%80%93Morrison_formula).

A statement on determinants can be derived with a small modification to the proof: take Equations (1) and (2) [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Woodbury_matrix_identity&oldid=627695139#Derivation_from_LDU_decomposition); compute determinants of the first and third member of those chains of equalities, and equate them:
$$
\det A^{-1}\det(C-VA^{-1}U)^{-1} = \det\begin{bmatrix}A & U\\V&C\end{bmatrix}^{-1} = \det(A-UC^{-1}V)^{-1}\det C^{-1};
$$
invert everything and you get
$$
\det A \det(C-VA^{-1}U) = \det(A-UC^{-1}V)\det C, \tag{*}\label{186699_star}
$$
which by continuity holds also when $\begin{bmatrix}A & U\\V&C\end{bmatrix}$ isn't invertible. Your two formulas can be derived easily from this one ($C=I$ in both cases).

Equation \eqref{186699_star} is also known as (the two versions of) *the Schur complement formula*; an equivalent statement appears for instance in the Wikipedia article [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Schur_complement&oldid=628405767) (last equation of the section titled [*Background*](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Schur_complement&oldid=628405767#Background)).

People in applied linear algebra often prefer talking about inverses than determinants, but it's essentially the same result.